# A simple yet powerful web site map design tool?

Tags: prototype, user-interface, sitemap

I just need to draw a sitemap as a document. Visio conceptual sitemap is an overkill and not friendly. I havent tried COnceptdraw.
What I am looking for is a simple lite tool. Good if I can make a flash or exe export so that I can send it to the client.

Comment: You should mention what OS you're on. Hard to recommend something without knowing the platform.

Comment: Dear Jeremy , Windows OS

Answer (score 8):

I would prefer [XMind](http://www.xmind.net/) for this kind of task. It's free and really nice and it is available for all major platforms out there.

Example with XMind:

[image]

If you are working under Mac, you can also try [Omnigraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) for this kind of task. But it costs money. But it's definitely worth it. :)

Also cool is [yED](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html). And it's free. This is done via yEd:

[image: Structure done with yEd]

Comment: They have different pricing models. See http://www.xmind.net/pricing/ it was free in 2011 when i wrote this posting.

Answer (score 3):

For what I tried, mind maps are the easiest way to plan the sitemap. It seems like a right balance of expressiveness and ease of use (and a low learning curve).

I'm designing my sitemap right at this moment using [FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

- I was able to start using it effectively in less than 1 hour
- It is really easy to use and efficient (just a few keystrokes to operate)
- The notes section is great to write down the punchlines of the pages
- last but not least, it's in Java, so cross platform

The tool is great for it's main purpose - mind mapping. The final result is NOT graphically appealing. On the upper side, you can export your map in a variety of portable/standalone formats (HTML/Java applet/Flash).

Answer (score 0):

I also like freemind.  The tool has a rough user interface, but the keyboard shortcuts make it insanely fast to build out a mind map.  My one quibble with doing a sitemap in it (which I am currently doing) is that it wants you to have your hierarchy flow to the left or right, and I would prefer my sitemap to flow down.

Also I would like a tool that allows me to put multiple pieces of info in for each page in a sitemap like the title, url, meta description, keyword, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is http://creately.com Simple and free to try. Examples are also provided!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a lot of tools but [Google Docs Drawings](http://docs.google/drawings) seems like the best.

Comment: Really just a comment!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not strict with stand alone application software.

**and**

If you are wishful to develop Sitemap behavior using web technologies. I can give several Options to you.

Advantage here is you can promptly give direct **weblink** to your client.

Some of the cool options are as below:

**1. JS - Mind Map**

Sample Preview :

[image]

It is **jquery** based library. Have good Animation backup. Good to do simple mind maps. **Plus Open Source.**

Link :- https://github.com/kennethkufluk/js-mindmap

**______________________________________________________________________________________**

**2 JS Plumb**

Sample Preview:

There are many preview options available [here](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/chart/jquery.html). One sample is as below.

[image]

JS Plumb library enables us to develop stuff the plumber way. They have various options Pipes , Nodes , Endpoints etc. It can be impplemented in various technologies like, JQuery , Mootools etc.
**Plus it is open source under MIT Licence.**

Link :- http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/home.html

**______________________________________________________________________________________**

**3. Arbor JS**

Sample Preview:

[image]

Arbor is a graph visualization library built with web workers and
jQuery. Rather than trying to be an all-encompassing framework, arbor
provides an efficient, force-directed layout algorithm plus
abstractions for graph organization and screen refresh handling.

Link : https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor

**_____________________________________________________________________________________**

Apart from this some other suggestions are...

**Infovis** - http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html

**d3.js** - http://d3js.org/

Answer (score 0):

Regardles of your OS you can use one of avaialble cloud based apps. I'm using Slickplan. It has many advanced features, like the site crawler, design mockups, flowchart maker, sharing via social media, Basecamp, Teamwork; exporting in several file formats. I can even work with my clients in real time and use chat to communicate. Also they offer several plans, so you can adjust them to your needs.